# Jquery Hide the element after input

Tags: jquery

JS/Jquery Disappear on focus next element / jquery on focus on element  hide previous element after there has been an input

I have the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").click(function(){
$("#hide").hide();
});
);
</script>
```

The above hides the element 'div' onclick. What I am really looking for is when I have filled the first field, and click on the second one, then it should hide the first one. The div should slide out. For eg I have 5 fields as Name, Email, DOB, Address, Post Code. So when I have entered my Name, and click on Email, the Name DIV should disappear by sliding out. I am new to JQuery.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You could hide your fields on blur but from a UX point of view it's very bad. How do you get back to the field you've just filled to change it in case you made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not a good idea to hide fields from the user, you could `fadeOut` each not empty field when `focus` is set on another field. This way you have at least possibility to get back to field when you click outside the form (it will be visible until any other field is not clicked).

```js
$(".txt").focus(function(){
  var inputs = $(".txt").not($(this)).not(".txt:hidden");
  if($(".txt").not(".txt:hidden").length == 2){
    $(".txt").focusout(function(){
      if($(this).val()){
        $(this).fadeOut();     
      }
    });
  }
  inputs.each(function(){
    if($(this).val()){
      $(this).fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><input type="text" class="txt" placeholder="Name"/></div>
<div><input type="text" class="txt" placeholder="Email"/></div>
<div><input type="text" class="txt" placeholder="DOB"/></div>
<div><input type="text" class="txt" placeholder="Address"/></div>
<div><input type="text" class="txt" placeholder="Post Code"/></div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhf0vjus/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple answer that you can easily extend:

```js
$('input#email').click(function(){
    if ($('input#name').val().length > 0 ){
        $('input#name').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='name' placeholder="name"></input><br>
<input id='email' placeholder="email"></input><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event using jQuery's `on()` or `bind()` methods. The event you care about is `blur` which triggers when an element loses focus.

Something like:

```
$('#name').on('blur', function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```